# Animate Canvas.drawline in android customview

Tags: canvas, draw, paint, progress, animated

I am currently working at a travel app, and I have a vertical line, that represents the progress made on your trip.
This is the onDraw function of my class:

```
  @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (paint != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(startingX, startingY, startingX, progress + startingY, paint);
        if (transitTrip) {

            if (ratio > progresses.get(0)) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(waypointPassedBig, startingX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (24 * Constants.density) + (0 * (totalProgress + 10 * Constants.density) / (progresses.size() - 1)), paint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawBitmap(waypointBig, startingX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (24 * Constants.density) + (0 * (totalProgress + 10 * Constants.density) / (progresses.size() - 1)), paint);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < progresses.size(); i++) {
                if (ratio > progresses.get(i)) {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(waypointPassed, startingX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (24 * Constants.density) + (i * (totalProgress + 10 * Constants.density) / (progresses.size() - 1)), paint);
                } else {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(waypoint, startingX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (24 * Constants.density) + (i * (totalProgress + 10 * Constants.density) / (progresses.size() - 1)), paint);
                }
            }
            if (ratio > progresses.get(progresses.size()-1)) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(waypointPassedBig, startingX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (24 * Constants.density) + ((progresses.size()-1) * (totalProgress + 10 * Constants.density) / (progresses.size() - 1)), paint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawBitmap(waypointBig, startingX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (24 * Constants.density) + ((progresses.size()-1) * (totalProgress + 10 * Constants.density) / (progresses.size() - 1)), paint);
            }
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, startingX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, progress + startingY - bitmap.getHeight() / 2, paint);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I first draw the line, then I draw my waypoints, and ultimately my position.
"progress" represents the progress on the trip from 0% to 100%.
Now, if the progress is 50% it will directly draw the line to half of the view. Now I need this to animate the line and not just simply appear.
How can I do this efficiently?
I tried setting a list of paths instead of "drawline", and in a for (i go through all the points of the line, and create for each one a line from the start, to that point). After that I tried settings a incrementor, and each onDraw only to draw from the start to the point from the path, represented by the incrementor, but like that it draw nothing.